# iPhone / iPad enterprise distribution problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, distribution, enterprise

I've just set up our iPhone / iPad Universal app to support Enterprise Distribution. I've hosted the provisioning profile, the plist file, and the application itself (the IPA file) on our private servers.

Users can go to Safari on their device and download the provisioning profile and it installs itself just fine. They can also view the plist file (we used this to test connectivity, etc).

However, no matter what we try the application file itself will not download. We navigate to our 'get' URL which sends back the manifest (plist) file, which in turn redirects to the application (IPA) file itself. Safari displays a 'Safari cannot download this file' error and we get a 'broken pipe' exception thrown on the server side.

I'm kinda stuck, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need anything but the plist and the IPA file, since nowadays the provisioning profile comes bundled in the IPA.

Did you create the plist yourself. or did you have XCode generate it for you with through the "Build and Archive" path in XCode?

Comment: Hi Kendall - thanks for your reply. I do indeed get XCode to generate the plist via the "Build and Archive" function.

Comment: Sorry - to continue... I note with interest that I do not require the provisioning profile - I will experiment with removing it. Should I not be building with the AdHoc profile? Perhaps I should build using the Release profile? Thanks again.

Comment: I usually copy the Release profile to make an ad-hoc build profile.  You also have the entitlements.plist in place?  Another way to test, would be to drag the .ipa file into iTunes and try loading it on a target iPhone that way, to see what errors (if any) it gives.