# iPhone Distribution Download Issue

Tags: iphone, cordova, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I'm having some trouble with the in-house enterprise app distribution that apple provides. I've already obtained the enterprise certificate and got the necessary files (p12, manifest, etc) and successfully built the app through phonegap build. The problem I'm having right now is that I'm unable to download the file from the server I've uploaded it onto. Whenever I attempt to do so from my phone, it gives me this error "Safari cannot download this file". Is this due to some sort of certification issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748312/iphone-ipad-enterprise-distribution-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced a number of problems with the enterprise deployment scheme myself. There are a number of things you will want to make sure of:

1. Make sure you're using the appropriate mobile provisioning profile.
2. Make sure that the server is set up to serve the `.plist` and `.ipa` files with a mime-type of `application/octet-stream`. If it is not, the iOS device will not be able to download them.
3. In your `.plist` file, make sure that the `<string>` property under `<key>url</key>` contains the full path to your `.ipa` file. This would be where you would download the file through your web-browser. Anything less won't work.
4. Install the app using an application specific URI of the form `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://yourserver.com/path/your.plist` where `yourserver.com` is the domain name of your server, `path` is the path to the directory on our server, and `your.plist` is the name of your `.plist` file.

Comment: The problem ended up being that phonegap build doesn't allow you to download the plist file, but only gives you an ipa file. So in the end, I had to make a php script to extract the ipa, pull the plist file and input the necessary info into the plist from the server itself so I can allow the user to install the app on the phone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just went through the same thing.  See Yatin comments.  since you have the signed ipa and let assume you have all your certificate in order.

1. You want to make sure you can download plist and ipa file.  We host ours on IIS server and had to add the mime types.
2. Make sure your install link is an full URL:  itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;amp;url=http://www.fullurl/to.ipa
3. Finally, make sure your mobile provision file has all the necessary device id/UUID.